# Can't use guzzle or curl in localhost

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I have a `laravel` project and I need to connect to a api but I'm having problems because the response is always `This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.`

I test the api with `postman` and works fine.

First I tried use `GuzzleHttp` but I thought there was a problem and I tried use `curl` but the response is the same.

Next I put the code in hosting and works well.

Next I create a index.php file in a mamp folder and works well too.

So the problem seems to be with `laravel`, something is blocking this connection and I don't know what is.

I'm using the new version of laravel with `php 7.2.19`.

I'm running this in a `os x`.

How can I solve this situation?

Thank you

**SOLUTION**
The solution for my problem was upgrade php. I had 7.2.9 version and upgrade to 7.2.23 and works. I don't know it it's a problem with some extension but works with this upgrade.

Thank you all for your answers

Comment: try the following package which I found useful and simple. Just let me know . https://github.com/ixudra/curl

Comment: @farooq I already tried this package too and result is the same.

Comment: So which API you are using ? Is this from different site or local or same laravel project ?

Comment: have you start your local server? and you can also write localhost instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @sandy Yes I can use localhost or 127.0.0.1 but the result is the same for both.

Comment: do you want to connect to different api from laravel project or , want to connect to laravel api through curl?

Comment: @KishoreKadiyala I want to connect to a different api, an external api. For example https://api-test/get-orders

Comment: can you open laravel project home page in browser? Did you set up virtual host for laravel project?

Comment: @KishoreKadiyala Yes I can. And in the route where I use curl if I comment the code and put a echo it execute. When I have the curl code it returns the This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

Comment: Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);` to force curl to use IPv4. IPv6 can sometimes cause issues.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is most likely with the vhost configuration or server configuration.

For nginx for example, to call the PHP interpreter, the domain (address) you're calling must be one of the aliases declared in your vhost, otherwise it will dismiss the call and return a 404.

Even if you want to do a local call, you would need to use a declared domain or have another declaration that limits the inbound IP to local.

Comment: Ok. How can I do that?

Comment: @user3242861 call your API with the declared domain as if it was external. that's the easiest way. the other solutions require some sysadmin knowledge.